# Android same layout different data

Tags: android, eclipse, string, layout

I'm creating a local android application and am trying the following:

The main menu consists of 4 buttons, each will lead to a (different) list of chapters.
The layout of the chapters view is the same, so I am trying to use one layout for every chapters page, by using different strings depending on the button that's being pressed at the main menu. So when the user presses button 1, the list of chapters differs from when the user presses button 2, etc.

I have tried looking up solutions, but was unable to find any so far. Is there a way to call a certain set of strings depending on the button that is chosen?

Comment: every chapter tends to every activity or what ?

Comment: I want to narrow down the activities by using one layout, but with different data. From main menu to list of chapters, and from chapter to a page with information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use a custom list adapter which take your array of strings as a parameter? Your list of chapter is just a simple listview with one string in each row right?

Comment: ListView did look like the easiest solution. You suggest covering it in Java and setting the strings from there?

Comment: If you have one string per row, you can use a simple adapter on your listview with your array.

Comment: `listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array));`